# many turbolinks when I browser back

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I am developing in Ruby on Rails.
I get many turbolinks when I use browser back like this.

[have many turbolinks linke this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsqYL.png)

Although I move page by clicking a tag, I have no turbolinks.
Only I use browser back, I have many turbolinks loading and reload webpage many times.

How can I browser back smoothly just like I click a tag.

Answer (score 0):

SO! not clear your question, for suggestion if you do not need `turbolinks` on your application then remove the `gem 'turbolinks'` from `Gemfile` update the bundle and remove `//= require turbolinks` this line from `assets/application.js` and finally restart the server.

**Number 2**

If need to disable `turbolinks` for specific link then use `data-turbolinks="false"` for this link which you need to not use `turbolinks` like below

```
<a href="/" data-turbolinks="false">Disabled</a>
```

See more about `turbolinks` on there [documentation](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#disabling-turbolinks-on-specific-links)

Hope it helps